# DOCKER network problems on the mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

The out-bound network connections fail on my Docker client (mac version), after running for an extended period of time. I'm running Docker on my mac (non-beta version of Docker, with the latest version of Sierra).

I launched a set of containers via Docker-compose, which connect to various web-services. The connections start out fine, with no issues, but then fail the very next day. That is, if I run a script like this: data = requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com"), it works perfectly when I launch the containers, but fails with a timeout error the next day. Moreover, if I attempt to rebuild the containers (stopping docker-compose), I see several DNS failures. BUT, my host system (my mac) is running fine, with no obvious problems. If I then restart the Docker client, everything works correctly.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Did you do a `docker logs <container-id>` to see why the container crashed?

Comment: The logs are how I can see the timeout and DNS errors

Comment: @vgoklani did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm running into the same issue now and a factory reset has not solved the problem.  restarting docker client seems to resolve issue but then it comes back after some time...